# Why is my car revving high when I get past 60km/hour

Tags: rpm

I have a 2005 nissan x-trail (ua-nt30, 1990cc 4wd) with just over 200,000km on the clock. It starts okay, idles okay and kicks back ok during gear shift. Revs remains okay (1,500-2,000 RPMs) when I drive from 0-60km/hour or maintain that speed. Problem starts when I go past 60km/hour speed, the rev goes up with speed! To get to 80km/hour even on downhill, the rev has to be 3,500 RPMs. To get 100km/hour, the rev is 4,000 RPMs and up it goes with higher speed. I maintain a gentle accelerator pressure for car to pick speed for itself and the engine does not whine during these high rev speeds, I even checked with a diagnoser if all the gears shifts and they do. I Changed transmission oil, changed transmission solenoids, changed spark plugs, checked/changed the speed sensor. And all these have yielded no results. I checked the fuel pump and checked the fuel filter, and it is okay. I even checked just to be sure that my clock is working okay. Did a full tank and drove on a highway at the high revs and the fuel was guzzled up fast? I am lost for what to check and I need help. The high revs are not economy friendly and driving at low speed is neither an option.

Comment: Of course revs go up with speed.  What are the revs at 60kph and the revs at 80kph and the revs at 100kph?

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is EXACTLY the way cars work.  In order to go faster the engine must turn faster.

So what you have said, 2000 rpm at 60 kph, 3000 rpm at 80, and 4000 at 100 kph is pretty much a linear relationship of rpm to kph.

If you don't want the engine to run so fast, slow down.

Comment: I thought that at a constant highway speed, a vehicle equipped with overdrive transmission, rpms are supposed to drop?

Comment: How do we know it's not already in OD?

Comment: Yes that is the way cars work, but my Revs seems high for those speeds. I have a similar car (Model, make and year of make) and revs seems ok. I can hit 140km/hr at below 2500 rpm and the only times i get to 3000 rpm is when going uphill

Comment: Faulty overdrive might be it @jwh20. The overdrive button seems only to work intermittently

Comment: Ummm, you might want to update your original posting with that vital information.  Of course the RPMs will still increase with speed but not as quickly.